# What are the most important differences between IDP3 and IDP-Z3

Tags: idp-z3

The newest version of the IDP system is called IDP-Z3 and is based on Microsoft's Z3 solver.
(see https://www.idp-z3.be/)

Both are based on the FO(.) language, but the syntax is slightly different.

What are the most important differences in syntax, semantics, functionality, philosophy ...?

Answer (score 4):

The IDP-Z3 docs contain [a subsection detailing syntax/functionality changes](https://docs.idp-z3.be/en/stable/FO-dot.html#differences-with-idp3), though it does not seem complete. It should probably be updated based on the answers received here.

Of the top of my head, other syntax changes are as follows.

Vocabulary:

- No more `isa ...` or `constructed from` for types. Regardless of the type, their interpretation is written as `T := {a, b, ...}` or `T := {0..10}`.
- All symbol declarations now follow the same structure: `symbol_name : arg_0 * .. * arg_n -> arg_m`.

Theory:

- Quantification syntax is now of the form `!x in Type` instead of `!x[Type]`.
- 0-ary symbols need to be applied by writing `()`, e.g. `p()`.
- The sum aggregate's syntax is now `sum(lambda t in T: phi)`. This can be combined with an `if .. then .. else ..` expression to have a conditional sum. An example: `total_cost() = sum(lambda x in items: if in_cart(x) then cost(x) else 0).` Min/max aggregates are also changed similarly.

Structure:

- Interpretations use `:=` instead of `=` and must end with a period, e.g. `p := true.` and `human := {Ann, Jef}.`.

Procedure: the procedure now runs Python instead of Lua. This is elaborated upon [in the docs](https://docs.idp-z3.be/en/stable/IDP-Z3.html#main-block).